# C++ vector there is extra space, but why the pointer still points to an undefined space?

Tags: c++

Here is my coding:

```
vector<int>a;
a.reserve(14);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) a.push_back(i);
a.end()++;
```

I distribute 14 memory， but I just use 10 memory in this vector, so there are four memory I can use, but when I make the tail pointer move one bit to point to the next memory, the compiler informs me that the tail pointer has pointed to a undefined space, why? There are four memory haven't been used, I don't understand that.

Here is the operation which the loop does:

```
                                a.end() --v   v-- a.end()++
 -------------------------------------------------------
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |   |   |   |   |
 -------------------------------------------------------
```

I just think that a.end()++ points to the 12th memory after a.end() which is existent. But why I can't make a pointer that points to that space?

Comment: [`end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end) returns the iterator pointing one off the end of your container, incrementing this is undefined behaviour

Comment: memory -> elements perhaps?

Comment: I edited my answer a bit, maybe it is more clear for you. If not ask for more information.

Answer (score 4):

There are two things to consider:

**1.**
Think of what [end()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/end/) is returning:

> Returns an iterator referring to the past-the-end element in the vector container.
>
> The past-the-end element is the theoretical element that would follow the last element in the vector. It does not point to any element, and thus shall not be dereferenced.
>   So end() returning an element that does *not* exists, it is useful for checking an iterator in a loop condition: `iter != vec.end()`.

**2.**
There is again misunderstanding of the **size** and the **capacity** of a STL container.

The [**size**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/capacity/) (get by `size()`) is the actual number of elements that are stored in a container. The size may not vary between different compiler. In your example you have [pushed back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) 10 elements inside it.

The [**capacity**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/capacity/) (get by `capacity()`) is the memory that your container is using under the hood. That means in your example you [reserved](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) 14 elements as capacity. You can put 14 elements into the vector without a reallocation needed to be happen.

---

**In short:** After your loop the vectors **size** is 10 and the **capacity** is 14. The iterator returned by `end()` points to the 11. element which does not exists. If you increment that you point to the 12. element which even does not exists. The [at()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/) method  of a vector is well explained when it comes to an out of bound access:

> The function automatically checks whether n is within the bounds of valid elements in the [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/vector), throwing an [out_of_range](http://www.cplusplus.com/out_of_range) exception if it is not (i.e., if n is greater than, or equal to, its [size](http://www.cplusplus.com/vector::size)).

That means you can just access within: `0 <= n < size()`.

---

Consider also that there is a [resize()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) function, which resizes the vector so that it contains the given number of elements. If you would use [resize()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) instead of [reserve()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) you have to use the [[] operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/) or the [at() method](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/), because if you would [push_back()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) more elements it would be behind the actual size.

---

**Out of bound access:**
If you want to access the memory that the [reserve()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) allocates right after the size, you can do it by `vec[vec.size() + n] ... // access invalid!` (**actually you should never do this!**). This is possible without that the compiler gives you a warning, because the compiler can **not** check the size of the vector here.
The program will even not crash on runtime because the memory of a vector is guaranteed to be continious. So as you said the memory is there right after the size. But you normally don't care how the vector is allocating and what is behind it's size. The vector class is a safe abstraction layer on top of the memory.

Comment: Hi @Kaiser if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I see no guaranteed way of accessing the vector's data at a position `size() < position < capacity()`, even if one might think that the underlying memory is reserved for `capacity()` number of elements. The reason is that the standard for class `vector`defines/guarantees access only in the range of `0..size()-1`, and implementations do not *have to guarantee* access beyond that range.

Take, for example, function [T* vector::data()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data), which ...

> Returns pointer to the underlying array serving as element storage.
>   The pointer is such that range [data(); data() + size()) is always a
>   valid range, even if the container is empty (data() is not
>   dereferenceable in that case)

Even if you get a pointer to the underlying memory structure, the standard does not guarantee access after the `size()`-position.

So even if an access like `int x = v.data[v.size()]` (assuming to be still in the range of capacity) will likely not crash, such an access relies on library implementation details, is therefore for sure not portable and probably introduces undefined behaviour.

Comment: I have edit my question you can see it.

Comment: I know that you can see it, and it is even likely that you can access it, but it is not officially supported.